# How to reduce I/O and memory usage when installing node.js on shared hosting?

Tags: node.js, linux

I've tried to install node.js via Putty on my shared hosting account with cPanel and CloudLinux. But at some moment I/O and physical memory usage reached to their limits and the installation process was stopped. My I/O usage limit is 10 MB and physical memory limit is 512 MB.

This happens when Putty displays the lines:

> -c -o /home/vikna211/node/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/api.o
>   ../deps/v8/src/api.cc

After that I see:

> make[1]:
>   [/home/vikna211/node/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/api.o]
>   Interrupt make[1]: Deleting intermediate file
>   `4095d8cbfa2eff613349def330937d91ee5aa9c9.intermediate' make: [node]
>   Interrupt

Is it possible to reduce the usage of both resources when installing node.js to successfully finish the process?

And maybe it's not a problem of memory. Maybe the process tries to delete that intermediate file, but can't do it and causes the memory crash.

Comment: That's an extremely limited VPS so you might be stuck compiling on another system and shipping a binary over. If your provider is that stingy, I'd look for a new one.

Comment: How much are minimal I/O and physical memory required for installing node.js?

Comment: Obviously more than what you have. I'm not sure of the exact requirements, they're not published nor easily discovered. It's hard to find a 512MB VPS these days as most are a minimum of 1GB for $5/mo, and I've never had problems compiling Node on a system like that, so it needs somewhere between 512MB and 1GB.

Comment: Can you open htop and see what else is using memory?

Comment: What is htop and how can I open it? Maybe it's not a problem of memory, maybe the installation process tries to delete that intermediate file (see my question above) but can't do it and causes the memory crash

Comment: Literally, if you put 'htop' into Google you'll get your answer. It will show you what processes are using memory. You may already have something running that is consuming a lot of a memory because 512 should be enough to install Node.